# Restricting multiple datepickers to certain days not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have the following code in a customdp.js file, for some reason it is not restricting the datepicker to the days I have chosen. You can see the test here and maybe someone can see why it is not working?

http://www.healthybrighton.co.uk/wse/node/1841

```
$(function() {

var pickable = { dp1296596522228: [1, 4] };
$('.webform-calendar hasDatepicker').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
        var day = date.getDay(), days = pickable[this.id];
        return [$.inArray(day, days) > -1, ""];
    }
  });
});​

});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I restrict multiple DatePickers to certain days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857184/how-do-i-restrict-multiple-datepickers-to-certain-days). Please try to update your original question with more information rather than opening a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you want it to work on load then you would put it in

```
$(function() {

var pickable = { dp1: [1, 4], dp2: [2, 5] };
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
        var day = date.getDay(), days = pickable[this.id];
        return [$.inArray(day, days) > -1, ""];
    }
  });
});​

});
```

Comment: Thankyou Victor, I did the above but still it is not working..weird - I have edited the orginal post, maybe you have some ideas on this?

Comment: This is because the IDs dont match because the ID is generated dynamically so its always changing.

Comment: Your right, drupal seems to change the input ID on every page load!  Any idea how to stop this happening?  SOrry i dont mean to be demanding, I just am a bit stuck,

Comment: sorry i dont know Drupal. But you could use something like .data() to store the array in the element itself.